# regular expression matching a string or none in mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I am doing one single regular expression to match the following urls to the appropriate files

```
/main/type1/dog/type2/food                index.php?t1=dog&t2=food 
/main/type1/dog/type2/food/               index.php?t1=dog&t2=food 
/main/type1/dog/type2/food/menu/puppy     index.php?t1=dog&t2=food&menu=puppy 
/main/type1/cat/type2/toy/menu/adult      index.php?t1=cat&t2=toy&menu=adult


RewriteRule ^/?main/type1/([a-z]+)/type2/([a-z]+)/?(|(menu)/([a-z]+))$   index.php?t1=$1&t2=$2&$menu=$3 [L]
```

But it doesn't work as I expect. Any clue from expert to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
^/?main/type1/([a-z]+)/type2/([a-z]+)(/|(/menu/([a-z]+)/?))?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?main/type1/([a-z]+)/type2/([a-z]+)(?:/(menu)/([a-z]+)|)/?$ index.php?t1=$1&t2=$2&$3=$4 [L]
```

This way, if the `menu` part doesn't exist, the parameter won't get passed into your index.php script.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are are fine with `&=` at the end of your query string it is better to have 2 separate rules like this:

```
# for URL with 2 query parameters
RewriteRule ^/?main/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?t1=$1&t2=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# for URL with 3 query parameters
RewriteRule ^/?main/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?t1=$1&t2=$1&$3=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```